# Angular Clicking on Text to show div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I was wondering how to accomplish this with Angular as it seems that `ng-click` is something to use,  then `ng-model` seems like that could be used.

I want to click on Text and then have a div show its contents and it is not working

My fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/gdxwtoL7/

```
<div class="well" ng-controller="MyController">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="selMe" ng-click="handleAnchorClick()">Enter Address</a>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div ng-if="selMe">
      adfadf
</div>
```

simple module and controller

```
  angular.module('myapp', []);
  angular.module('myapp').controller('MyController', MyController)

  function MyController($scope) {

  }
```

Comment: i'm not doing anything with ng-click,  but i guess i thought the ng-model would know about event like click ,

Comment: how can i just show the div with a click on the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller has to be aware of the div you want it to show.
the `ng-if` is waiting for the value of the `selme` which you can alter from the controller.
The `ng-model` binds your data to your controller in adding two-way data binding.
I made a little enhancement to your code to toggle the div when the text is clicked multiple times.
https://jsfiddle.net/gdxwtoL7/2/

```
<div class="well" ng-controller="MyController">

  <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="selMe" ng-click="handleAnchorClick(selMe)">Enter Address</a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div ng-if="selMe">
    adfadf
  </div>
</div>

angular.module('myapp', []);

angular.module('myapp').controller('MyController', MyController)

function MyController($scope) {
 $scope.handleAnchorClick = function (selMe) {
   $scope.selMe = !selMe
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything inside the ng-click function, and you have the ng-if outside of the controller linked to the variable inside it.

https://jsfiddle.net/gdxwtoL7/1/

HTML

```
<div class="well" ng-controller="MyController">
<a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="handleAnchorClick()">Enter Address</a>
<br>
<br>
  <div ng-if="selMe">
    adfadf
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('myapp', []);

angular.module('myapp').controller('MyController', MyController)

function MyController($scope) {
 $scope.handleAnchorClick = function () {
   $scope.selMe = true
 }
}
```

Comment: while your fiddle is fine, the HTML embedded in the answer doesn't show how where to put `ng-controller`

Comment: Sorry, the creation of the div is being a pain and won't show in the code here. (Fixed)

Comment: so do i need an ng-model?  and do i need ng-click ?

Comment: You just need ng-click no need for ng-model.

Comment: I had already created a quick plunker while @MikeHughesIII replied.

Answer (score 0):

> The ***ngModel*** directive binds an *input*,*select*, *textarea* (or > custom form control) to a property on the scope using ***NgModelController***, which is created and exposed by this directive.
>
> ***ngModel*** is responsible for:
>
> - Binding the view into the model, which other directives such as input, textarea or select require.
> - Providing validation behavior (i.e. required, number, email, url).
> - Keeping the state of the control (valid/invalid, dirty/pristine, touched/untouched, validation errors).
> - Setting related css classes on the element (ng-valid, ng-invalid, ng-dirty, ng-pristine, ng-touched, ng-untouched, ng-empty, ng-not-empty) including animations.
> - Registering the control with its parent form.
>
> The ***ngClick*** directive allows you to specify custom behavior when an element is clicked.
>
> Note : we need ng-click to capture the event and manipulate the data stored in ng-model.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple code without the need of controller:

```
<div class="well">
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="" ng-click="show=true">Enter Address</a>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div ng-show="show">
 adfadf
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @MikeHughesIII already pointed out, outside of your controller you can't reach $scope variables.

I am adding a quick snippet made after Mike's answer for completeness sake, showing a show/hide (toggle) approach, where the function sets the visibility variable to the opposite of its current status (true or false) when the function is invoked.

Hope that helps to clarify the issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.2" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <h1>Hello {{hello}}!</h1>
    <a href ng-click="toggleDivVisibility()">Enter your address</a>
    <br>
    <textarea ng-if="visible" name="address" id="address" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
  </div>

  <script>
    angular.module('myApp', []);

    angular.module('myApp')
      .controller('myController', myController);

    function myController($scope) {
      $scope.hello = "world";
      $scope.visible = false;
      $scope.toggleDivVisibility = function() {
        $scope.hello = 'mondo';
        $scope.visible = !$scope.visible;
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```